# How to match string pattern?

Tags: python

I have a dataset where each row of 2 of the columns contain a string like this -

- WO-05078125: AN20033315: Ordered part for customer to exchange
- WO-04981906: AN19550541: Answered Biomed questions

I am trying to get rid of the first parts `WO-05078125: AN20033315:`. The numbers could be different but it is always the same pattern.

How can I solve this please ?

Comment: split at ":" and take just the last item, strip redundant spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by dataset? txt file? some library parsed object?

Comment: split like this string_variable = full_string.split(":")[1] or [2] if you also want to get grid of the second pattern

Comment: @buran or just slice with `[25:]` as it's consistently `WO-{8 digits}: AN{8 digits}: ` in his examples

Comment: Thank you all for your response. How about if i have to match either one or both of the pattern in the string. Splitting by ':' would not be so efficient here because i have also something like this many times in the same string.

Comment: @Jane, you can use what sudden_appearence suggested, or you can use [2:] items and just ':'.join` them back. Of course you can always use regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most straightforward approaches to solving your problem is using regex, but I do not mean using the `re` module directly. Instead you can use `pandas` and one of its inbuilt functions named `repalce`. You can gain more insight into the process by looking at the code below. Since you didn't provide a reproducible example, I made a dataframe with your input examples.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"myColumn": ["WO-05078125: AN20033315: Ordered part for customer to exchange", "WO-04981906: AN19550541: Answered Biomed questions"]})

df["replaced"] = df["myColumn"].str.replace("WO\-\d+\:\sAN\d+\:\s", "")
df
```

##### Output

|  | myColumn | replaced |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | WO-05078125: AN20033315: Ordered part for customer to exchange | Ordered part for customer to exchange |
| 1 | WO-04981906: AN19550541: Answered Biomed questions | Answered Biomed questions |

##### Explanation

`WO\-\d+\:\sAN\d+\:\s` is the pattern we are using in this case. It replace the desired part with empty string("").

Comment: Thank you so much. Someone commented earlier to use regular expressions and I was already struggling with matching it. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions.

```
import re
re.sub(pattern, repl(acement), string)
```

As you don't want to replace it with anything you could just use an empty string to get rid of it. You can use  'WO-05078125: ' as pattern but you can also use special characters like **\d (digit)** or stuff like that. [For More Click Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could solve your problem.

```
rows = ["WO-04981906: AN19550541: Answered Biomed questions", "WO-05078125: AN20033315: Ordered part for customer to exchange", ......]
first_part = []
second_part = []
last_part = []
for row in rows:
    split_row = row.split(":")
    first_part.append(split_row[0])
    second_part.append(split_row[1])
    last_part.append(split_row[2])
```

In `first_part` will be all `"WO-XXXXXXXX"`, in `second_part` will be all `"ANXXXXXXXX"` and in `last_part` will be all descriptions.